# Do channel ids for guide categories (like music) change in the YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube-api

[After fetching the list of channels from the guide with the `guideCategories` endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories), a list of kind `youtube#guideCategory` is returned.  These IDs can be used to [get a list of channels from the `channels` endpoint for the given category](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels).

My question is do these IDs change?  Can I store this list of guide categories and reuse them for multiple languages/regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it works the same way as [VideoCategories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17738994) do, the IDs should work for and remain consistent across any region that supports it.

For example, when I used the API explorer and specified USA, Germany, or Australia for the region, the guideCategory ID for Music (GCTXVzaWM) was available for all three, so that guideCategory is supported in and will work for all three of those regions.