# How to make request to Youtube api with search term, video category, keywords, description and some other parameters?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to know how to combine multiple parameters in one request. For example, I'm using this https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/ for searching and these are my parameters:

```
var params = {
    part: 'snippet',
    key: 'my key',
    q:"cat",
    maxResults:50,
    videoCategories:["education", "science and technology"]
};
```

This is not working. I want to make a call with the specific search term, video categories, keywords, description and few others if needed. If users search for "Java", I want to return only videos in the categories of "education", "science and technology".

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues:

1) You're missing a necessary parameter, **type**. In your case you want this to be `type: 'video'`.

2) Video categories can't be specified by name. They have to be specified by code. They can be retrieved by the [VideoCategories:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list#usage) service, but luckily there's [a very handy list in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35877512/2575069). **Education** is *27*, and **Science & Technology** is *28*.

3) You can't specify more than one category for a given search; you'll have to do separate searches. <sup>*</sup>

Given all that, your parameters should look more like this:

```
var params = {
    auth: 'my key',
    part: 'snippet',
    type: 'video',
    videoCategoryId: '27',
    q: 'cat',
    maxResults: 50
};
```

* **NOTE:** While I was able to get search results from an arrayed videoCategoryId, the API only pays attention to the first value. Was able to prove this by searching for "surfing" with `videoCategoryId: ['1','39']`, which returned results. However, the same search with `videoCategoryId: ['39','1']` returned no results (not an error; just no results).