# How to use Youtube API v3 to filter out videos by category?

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to build a Youtube query in python that filters out, for instance, category 39 - Horror.
I'm looking to something similar to this:

```
searchResults = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', {
    maxResults: "10",
    q: "The ring",
    type: "video",
    videoCategoryId: "-10"
  });
```

Or any kind of workaround.

I even contemplated searching without filter and then try to exclude the ones from that category, but the information provided by the query does not include the category of the video. And it's pretty ugly as I really want 10 results, and I may need to make more queries in order to fill the list.

All I've found googling is how to get videos from the specified category.

Can you help me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the YouTube Data API, you can check here the existing videoCategories.

In this [demo available in the Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videoCategories.list?part=snippet&regionCode=US&fields=items(id%252Csnippet)%252Ckind&_h=2&), you can retrieve the videoCategories.

Once you have selected the `videoCategoryId`, use the following search request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&q=The+ring&regionCode=US&type=video&videoCategoryId=1&fields=items(id(channelId%2CvideoId)%2Csnippet(channelId%2CchannelTitle%2Cdescription%2Ctitle))%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CregionCode&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Here, I'm using the `search.list` request for get videos "from the US region", with `videoCategoryId` 1 = `(Film & Animation)` and retrieving the `title` of the YouTube video, its `videoId`, the `channel title` and `channel_id` from the channel who uploaded the video.

Here is the [demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=10&q=The%20ring&regionCode=US&type=video&videoCategoryId=1&fields=items(id%252FvideoId%252Csnippet(channelId%252CchannelTitle%252Cdescription%252Ctitle))%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CregionCode&_h=8&).

It seems that the `videoCategoryId` is not supported in all regions *(this might be the reason I couldn't retrieve videos with `videoCategoryId=39` "which is the Horror category in the US")*.

For more information, [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17738994/4092887).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but maybe I did not word the question properly. What I mean by filter out a category is to exclude one or more categories from my search. In the example of my question I want 10 videos resulting from searching "The ring" that does NOT belong to category 39.

Comment: @HuevoPodrido then you have to get the `videoIds` returned by the request to "search.list" and make other request to "videos.list", there, you pass the `videoId` *separared by commas* and check its `categoryId`, and in your code, ignore the videos with the given videoCategory. Check this [demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&id=lbO9LhD9PsI%252CPFsl1cGHzp4%252C5bXpMRkwm_8%252Chpb2-ZOzc_o%252Clm9AoNNWiPc&fields=items(id%252Csnippet(categoryId%252CchannelId%252CchannelTitle%252Ctitle))&_h=3&). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guess that's the closest I can get.

Comment: @HuevoPodrido you welcome. I'm glad to help and *(as you might noticed)*, YouTube Data API is *kind of* limited for specific tasks. Best you can do is rearrange the results according to your purposes.